# FPGA vs. Arduino for a PID Controller

Tags: arduino, fpga, pid-controller

I'd like to use an FPGA or an Arduino asa PID controller, and was wondering which device would be better to use? It will be used in a lab, and needs to be fast. Can I get all those in an Arduino without having to pay the extra money for an FPGA? Or will the larger price tag be worth it? Thanks!

Comment: What does 'fast' mean to you? 10 samples per second is fast in some contexts..

Comment: Too much hand waving.  In any case, it's not about the price, since a FPGA will cost less than a whole arduino board.  The real cost is the development time.  Also, there are a lot more things out there that can do PID control than arduinos and FPGAs.  Just about any micro can do this, depending on what your useless spec of "fast" really means.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity. My lab currently uses expensive controllers, and I've been trying to find a cheaper alternative that's comparable (or better) in performance. The devices currently in use are similar to this http://www.newport.com/High-Speed-Servo-Controller/984080/1033/info.aspx

Comment: OK, so what speed (updates/second) do you need? (You do the lookup work, and anyway what you *need* is not necesarily the same as what you current thingy *delivers*.)

Comment: Do you have prior experience with either FPGAs or C/C++ programming?  If neither, the Processing language (based C/C++) for Arduino  is probably easier to get up to speed than VHDL or Verilog used for programming FPGAs (just my opinion).

Answer (score 3):

The absolute majority of PI(D) controllers in the world are implemented on 8/16/32-bit microprocessors.  For example, Microchip has sold over 10 billion microcontrollers as of 2011.  Another example: GE uses 99% microcontrollers and 1% FPGA for control loop execution (reaction on @Eugene Sh).

Some of my control loops for power electronics are run at 200 kHz and it's all on the C2000 series from TI- digital signal controllers (32-bit).

FPGAs are for the high-end stuff, such as MRI, ultrasound, etc.

I'd suggest that unless you need super high execution speed/MHz bandwidth or would like to learn VHDL/Verilog then stay with Arduino.  <s>It certainly has better source-base than FPGAs.</s>  It is much easier to get started with Arduino than with FPGAs.

Arduino Uno also can also sample analog signals, which FPGAs cannot without an external ADC chip.  E.g. look at the Mercury FPGA card (http://www.micro-nova.com/mercury/).

The picture below shows the analog ports on the Arduino Uno board.

[image]

Comment: Right now we're currently using these but at around 1 KHz, so the bandwidth isn't much of a problem, but would an Arduino be able to keep up in speed?
http://www.newport.com/High-Speed-Servo-Controller-Model-LB1005/984080/1033/info.aspx

Comment: This answer is very opinionated and somewhat misleading. FPGAs are used in much simpler applications than stated. It is application defined whether or not to use them, and it is not speed-only considerations. The statement of the source base is arguable as well. Have you seen [Opencores](http://opencores.org/)? The only thing I would agree - it's better for one to stay with Arduino until knowing how to figure out the answer for such question themselves.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks for the feedback, I have edited the answer to sounds less opinionated.  I did look at OpenCores, it looks like a great resource.  However, I do think that FPGAs are much harder to get started with than Arduinos.